# Function Space and Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of all functions
$$f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
over $\mathbb{R}$

Determine if the set of all polynomials of degree 3 form a subspace.
The subset is the defined as
$$S:\{f\mid f(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{3}a_{i}t^i,\forall a_{i}\in\mathbb{R}:a_{3}\neq0,t\in[-1,1]\}$$

How is the zero vector defined in this case?

The vector addition in case of function space is defined as
$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x):f,g \in W, x\in F$$
Where $W$ is some function space over field $F$. The zero vector is then defined as the additive identity of the elements over the vector space of vector addition. If $\theta$ be the zero vector we have
$$f-f=\theta$$
$$\implies (f-f)(x)=\theta(x)$$
$$f(x)-f(x)=\theta(x)$$
$$\theta(x)=0$$
So $\theta$ is a function that maps from domain to the zero element of its range for all elements of the domain.
So in the context of my question, the zero vector should be the function such that
$\theta :\theta(t)=0 \forall t\in [-1,1]$ 
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the zero vector in this space is the zero function.

Comment: yes it's correct.

Comment: Then the zero vector does not exist because $a_{3}\neq 0$ implies all coefficients cannot simultaneously be 0 for the zero vector to map to 0 for all values of t in [-1,1] and hence this is not a subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest, the only possibility for the zero vector should be the zero polynomial (it is the only function such that $f+0=f$). However, $0$ is not a polynomial of degree $3$ - the deduction is that the subset of polynomials of degree *exactly* three are not a vector space.

However, the space of polynomials of degree *at most* $3$ is indeed a vector space. Can you see its dimension?

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. I've done the at most example before. The dimension would be 4 as the basis is $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't got a zero vector in your subset by the fundamental theorem of algebra (a degree $n$polynomial has at most $n$ real roots). Therefore no subspace. ..